# SSRS Sum values by week,month,and year

Tags: reporting-services

[Report value of stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38UIK.png)
I've created a stock value report.
The problem occurs with the addition of columns (month, year). I would like to set it to show the value of the last week in the month and year.

Comment: Is the report grouped by Year, Month, Week Number?

Comment: Hello Ross, thank you for your answer. Yes of course my report is grouped by year,Month and week number. Week number i count by expression =DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Fields!Datum.Value),month =Month(Fields!Datum.Value), year =Month(Fields!Datum.Value). Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I am following. You want to keep the Month and Year group but only have the summation of all weeks in the month as the value by month?

Comment: I want to keep the Month and Year group, but the summation for month a year i would like value of  last week.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment I think I know the best way for you to get there.

You want only the value of the last week within a Year/Month/Week column group. I would keep all the groups the way you have them setup with two small tweaks.

1. Drop the detail of the week group, keep the group, just no detail column group band.
2. Add a column group footer to the week group and simply apply the value as

   =Last(Fields!WeekValue.Value)

That way you should have Year/Month and one column for weeks, the footer column and you simply pull across the last value from within that group.